# Service crashes when using AppleScript to click menu bar icon

Tags: macos, applescript, menu-bar, bug, services

The following AppleScript code clicks the WiFi icon found in the menu bar [(source)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27388186):

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "SystemUIServer" to tell (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1) to click
```

Please complete the following steps to reproduce the bug:

1. In Automator.app, click <kbd>File</kbd> → <kbd>New</kbd> → <kbd>Service</kbd>.
2. Drag a <kbd>Run AppleScript</kbd> action to the workflow.
3. Paste the above line of code into the AppleScript body.
4. Save and title the *Service*.
5. Run the *Service*.

The WiFi icon is never clicked, and I am instead presented with the following (painfully ambiguous) error message:

[image]

Observations about this bug:

- The code works properly when compiled and tested in Script Editor or Automator.
- The *Service* works properly when the *Service* is triggered from within Automator (i.e., when the the frontmost application is Automator).
- The bug persists no matter which menu bar icon is specified.
- Adding administrator privileges does not solve the issue: `do shell script "osascript -e 'tell application \"System Events\" to tell process \"SystemUIServer\" to tell (menu bar item 1 of menu bar 1) to click'" password "thePassword" with administrator privileges`

---

Do you know what might cause this conflict?

Does a workaround exist, so that a menu bar icon can indeed be clicked by an AppleScript *Service*?

---

<sub>OS X El Capitan, version 10.11.6.</sub>

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me on the latest version of macOS Sierra.

I followed your steps exactly.  However, this code you posted needed to be tweaked to work on my system correctly.   Here is the code I used and placed into an Automator run AppleScript action

```
tell application "System Events"
    click menu bar item 3 of menu bar 1 of application process "SystemUIServer"
end tell
```

I also did get the same error message you got when i tried to run the service from within Finder (after successfully running the script within Automator and ScriptEditor)

On a hunch, I added Finder app to the list of allowed apps to control my computer.

[image]

Then I went back to Finder services menu and attempted to run the service again.  Bingo! It worked.  I did the same thing with several other applications I had open and it did not produce the error message

Comment: I appreciate the functional solution. The only downside is that I must essentially add *every* application that is installed on my computer to the list of apps that can control my computer (because the Service will conceivably be triggered from any app). It'll just be a bit of a chore to do this (and it will defeat the very purpose of this system security feature, of course).

Comment: I reread your answer a few times, and then I reread my previous comment a few times. Something felt strange. Our exchange got me feeling intense déjà vu. It turns out... [**this ain’t our first rodeo**](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/270773#comment341425_271166) ;-). The workaround for your solution is to simply save the `tell application "System Events"...` code as a dedicated .app file, grant this *one* application assistive access in System Preferences, and then activate this .app file in the AppleScript code of the Service.